# Laravel - GuzzleHttp Client throwing cURL error 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, curl, guzzle

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

try {    
    $this->client = new Client(['base_uri'=>'']);  
    $responseData = $this->client->request('URL',[
        'verify'  => false,
        'headers' => [
            'Accept'       => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ],  
    ]);
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage()." ".$ex->getLine()." ".$ex->getFile();
}
```

cURL error 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection  (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) 186 /var/www/api/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php

Answer (score 1):

There are many similar questions already. Try to debug it with `curl` console command and [this article](http://blog.techstacks.com/2010/03/3-common-causes-of-unknown-ssl-protocol-errors-with-curl.html), because there is not one reason for the error (the error is general).

Comment: would love to see solution.

Comment: As I said above, the error is general, it can be caused by many reasons. So no solution without additional debug info.